# Is Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux compatible with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2014, centos6, unixodbc

I am trying to use Microsoft ODBC Driver ***11*** for SQL Server  to connect with a SQ: Server instance running SQL Server  2014.

I am getting the following error message when attempting to connect:
ERROR SQLDriverConnect(): failed: [HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired.

The Microsoft Release Notes for  Microsoft ODBC Driver ***13*** state "*With Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.0 for SQL Server, SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 are now also supported.*"

To me, that suggest that prior versions of the driver do not support SQL 2014. But I  need to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to SQL Server 2014+ please use ODBC v13. v11 only supports SQL Server 2012 and below. Are you using the driver on Windows or Linux?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730315(v=sql.110).aspx, "The ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server supports connections to SQL Server 2014".